# How do I create a segmented circular progress bar in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard, uikit

I wanted to create a progress bar as shown in the image:

[image: Desired result]

I used the code mentioned in [this blog](https://medium.com/flawless-app-stories/multi-segment-progress-indicator-on-swift-87887ce7f80)
but I am unable to add separators and reduce the space between them.

I have managed to do like this through storyboard:

[image: Current result]

How can I change the code or is there any easier way to create?

Answer (score 1):

You didn't specify what sort of animation you want on your progress indicator, but certainly achieving the *drawing* you've shown in your first screenshot shouldn't be any problem; I was able to throw this together in a couple of minutes:

[image]

Each thing in that drawing (other than the face) is a CAShapeLayer: the dark background circle a shape layer, the animated green circle in front of it is a shape layer, and each of the eight little lines that indicate the segments is a shape layer. So I have ten shape layers in total. They are added in that order, so that the little lines appear in front of everything else.

If the goal is to "fill" each segment in discrete steps, rather than a smooth animation through all values, that's a trivial modification of what I've already described.

Comment: I am able to animate the progress but unable to create the progress as you have shown. If you can share the code of CAshapeLayer  i’ll try

Comment: I have described exactly what I'm doing (improved my description to be clearer). It seems to me that at this point I have "shared" much more about my code does than you have about yours.

Comment: its clear now. i have managed to do as you have described